# How to display a web form fields based on the user interacts

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have to develop a system which allows me to give a preview of the fields based on the user is connected. For example, we have 3 Combobox. The administrator can see and use all 3 Combobox, while simple one user only 2. How can I do this on a Webform?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The better Drupal way to do it is to use Permission.

In you module, declare the following :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission
 */
function yourmodule_permission() {
    return array(
        'access combobox 1' => array(
            'title'       => t('Access combobox 1'),
            'description' => t('Allow user to view combobox 1')
        ),
        'access combobox 2' => array(
            'title'       => t('Access combobox 2'),
            'description' => t('Allow user to view combobox 2'),
        ),
    );
}
```

then, in your form, use this permissions to display your combobox :

```
// Définition du composant du choix du schéma de base.
    $form['combobox_1'] = array(
            '#access'        => user_access('access combobox 1'),
            '#type'          => 'select',
            '#title'         => 'yourtitle',
            '#options'       => array_keys(...),
    );

    $form['combobox_2'] = array(
            '#access'        => user_access('access combobox 2'),
            '#type'          => 'select',
            '#title'         => 'yourtitle',
            '#options'       => array_keys(...),
    );
```

And then, just need to check which user role have this permission in your "**/admin/people/permissions**" page ;)

Comment: Is there a module to do it?

Comment: This feature is directly provide by Drupal core. You just need to write the correct hook ;)

Comment: Thanks @M.Be, can you help me to do this operation? I'm a neophyte to Drupal.
1. I've insert the hook block into module Webform, changing combobox into User Reference (Because I have a need to create a Selection Option of users).
2. Where do I enter the second block of code?
Thanks soo Much

Comment: The second block of code is the standard way to declare Drupal form component. So, you should build your form with this kind of component. For more information about it, you can read and bookmark the folloxing link : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x

To answer your questions :
1 : Change whatever you want, just be consistent ;)
2 : Inside the method which define you webform, maybe a hook_form if you use it ? i.e "yourmodule_form" ?

Comment: I Create the form by graphical way, where is the method which define my webform(Folder)? Excuse me for my questions

Comment: I don't know where the webform module put the equivalent of "hook_form" hook. I always create my form manually with field API. I suggest you to try this way ;) I can help you on drupal mechanism, but not more on the webform module ;)

Comment: I'm trying to follow your suggestion. I have integreted the first block, but i have some problem to understand the type of elements to put into second. Can you help me understand again?
Thanks

Comment: What did you try about it ? I don't see how to help you more... did you check the following link  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x ? You should find all you need to know about Drupal form component... And then, if you have some problem, ask with more détails ;)